# Using SQLAlchemy to filter by day in a date field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to work out how to filter by a day in a date field. If I have a date of birth field, how do I get every person that has a birthday on the 24th on all the months?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `extract()` function creates an appropriate `EXTRACT(field FROM expr)` expression for the database engine in use. Extract the `day` field from the column and compare it to your day value.

```
session.query(Person).filter(extract('day', Person.birthdate) == 24).all()
```

- SQLAlchemy docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=extract#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Extract
- PostgreSQL docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT
- SQLite docs: https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html
- MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract